# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE inserting blank record

Tags: mysql, insert, load-data-infile, blank-line

Trying to import text file using below command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/colleges.txt' 
INTO TABLE selections LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
SET unit=null, created=NOW(), type="college";
```

**Table Structure**

```
id   INT Autoincremented
name Varchar
type Varchar
unit Varchar
crated datetime
```

But the above command is adding blank value for `name` field.

Here is my sample text file:

```
American River College
American University
Amherst College
```

(http://india-webdev.com/demo/colleges.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the list of columns that are directly mapped from the text file surrounded in `()`, just before the `SET` clause:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/colleges.txt' 
INTO TABLE selections 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
-- Here, list columns from the file in ()
(name)
-- Followed by columns for which you set values
SET
  unit=null,
  created=NOW(),
  type="college";
```

Given your input data, this is tested and working on my development database.

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from selections;
+----+------------------------+---------+------+---------------------+
| id | name                   | type    | unit | created             |
+----+------------------------+---------+------+---------------------+
|  1 | American River College | college | NULL | 2015-02-16 08:08:01 |
|  2 | American University    | college | NULL | 2015-02-16 08:08:01 |
|  3 | Amherst College        | college | NULL | 2015-02-16 08:08:01 |
+----+------------------------+---------+------+---------------------+
```

It is a little ambiguous in the documentation:

```
...snip...
[LINES
        [STARTING BY 'string']
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    ]
    [IGNORE number LINES]
    -- HERE....
    [(col_name_or_user_var,...)]
    [SET col_name = expr,...]
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html